# rquery: Connect to specific schema in Postgres DB

Tags: r, rquery

The `rquery` package has been out for some time now, but the documentation is still very sparse. There isn't even a tag yet in SO, this question will create it.

Maybe there is someone who can help me nevertheless.

I want to connect to a schema in my Postgres-DB via `rquery`to read the data into R with all the speed it promises.

Using this code it works with all the tables in the `public`-schema.

```
library(RPostgres)
library(rquery)

con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                 host = #####,
                 dbname = #####,
                 user = #####,
                 password = ######)

df <- db_td(con, "tablename")  %.>%
        execute(con, .)
```

Now when I want to access a table in a specific schema `db_td()` has the argument `qualifiers =` which is an

> optional named ordered vector of strings carrying
>   additional db hierarchy terms,such as schema

So I did:

```
db_td(db, "tablename", qualifiers = c(schema = "schema"))
```

But:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) :    Failed to prepare
>   query: FEHLER:  Relation Â»tablenameÂ« existiert nicht LINE 1: SELECT
>   * FROM "tablename" LIMIT 1

So the `qualifiers =` argument seems to be completely ignored.

My question is thus pretty basic:

**How can I connect to a schema in a PostgresDB via rquery?**

Comment: not used this package, but did you try just using `"schema.tablename"` for the table_name?

Comment: Yes I have. I get the same error however. Probably because it's looking for `schema.tablename` inside the `public` schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/WinVector/rquery/issues/9) on github. So far regular `rquery` indeed doesn't have schema ability. The development version of `rquery` (`1.3.4`) however has, as of today, basic schema ability.

To be installed via:

```
library(devtools)

install_github("WinVector/rquery",  host = "https://api.github.com")
```

[Here](https://github.com/WinVector/rquery/blob/schema_qualification/db_examples/RPostgres_schema.md)'s a small instruction. Seems to have been inteded to work just as I was trying in my question.

Be careful though, `rquery` hasn't been fully tested in schema-mode and some things might not work.

**EDIT:** rquery now has full schema support.

Answer (score 2):

all my attempts to solve this "within" `rquery` seem to fail miserably, but you can work around it by doing something like:

```
dbExecute(con, "SET search_path = foo_schema, public;")
```

before you run `db_td`.

I think it's caused by [`rq_colnames` doing](https://github.com/WinVector/rquery/blob/master/R/db_ops.R#L167):

```
paste0("SELECT * FROM ", quote_identifier(db, table_name), 
        " LIMIT 1")
```

and hence not doing anything with its `qualifiers`, at least this matches the error I get back.

maybe report a bug/issue with `rquery` if this isn't enough

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was aware of that workaround. I'm about to create an issue on github. If I get an answer I'll post it here.